# How can I open a new WPF windows in second monitor?

Tags: wpf, windows, monitor

I'm trying to open a new WPF Window in a second monitor from a Windows located in the primary monitor. Following what I founded in other threads and discussions I wrote this:

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Screen s1 = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[1];
 System.Drawing.Rectangle r1 = s1.WorkingArea;
 form.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
 form.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
 form.Top = r1.Top;
 form.Left = r1.Left;
 form.Show();
 form.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

but this code not work: the new window is shown in the primary monitor. How I can resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use r.X and r.Y instead of r.top and r.left:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen s1 =    System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[1];
System.Drawing.Rectangle r1 = s1.WorkingArea;
form.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
form.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
form.Top = r1.Y;
form.Left = r1.X;
form.Show();
form.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

now it works.